# App_HiltComponents.ActivityC scoped with @dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ActivityScoped may not reference bindings with different scopes

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

After i change Dagger-android to Hilt, I got following error.

```
  @Provides @Singleton @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory com.zhixin.wedeep.common.di.NetWorkModule.provideGsonConverterFactory(com.google.gson.Gson)
  @Provides @Singleton @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull com.google.gson.Gson com.zhixin.wedeep.common.di.NetWorkModule.provideGson()
  @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.dao.CommentDao com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.di.HomePageDataModule.provideCommentDao(com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.HomePageDatabase)
  @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.HomePageDatabase com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.di.HomePageDataModule.provideHomePageDatabase(android.app.Application)
  @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.dao.CompositionDao com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.di.HomePageDataModule.provideCompositionDao(com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.HomePageDatabase)
  @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.dao.CompositionsDao com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.di.HomePageDataModule.provideBriefCompositionDao(com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.HomePageDatabase) [com.zhixin.wedeep.main.App_HiltComponents.ApplicationC �� com.zhixin.wedeep.main.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC �� com.zhixin.wedeep.main.App_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
```

Who has ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am new with HILT too, I met up this kind of error. I guess you provide object with @Singleton pls remove this annottion

Comment: Yes, I solved this problem by removing its ```@Singleton``` annottion

Comment: I did not figure it out yet, why like this?

Comment: Because every component has its scope. Application component scope is Singleton . You can refer doc[https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-scopes]